# Error when adding event listener to element when inside a class

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the code I get an error that says :
Uncaught TypeError: this.startButton.addEventlistener is not a function which I do not know how to fix.

I can console.log the button inside the class but cannot add the event listener which is weird

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="duration" />
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>


    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
class Timer{
    constructor(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton){
        this.durationInput = durationInput;
        this.startButton = startButton;
        this.pauseButton = pauseButton;


        this.startButton.addEventlistener('click',this.start)

    }


    start(){
        console.log("time to start the timer")
    }

}

const durationInput = document.querySelector('duration');
const startButton = document.querySelector('#start');
const pauseButton = document.querySelector('#pause');

const timer = new Timer(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton)
```

Comment: Two typos: 1) (mentioned in answer) `addEventListener` is the name of the function, and 2) missing `#` before `duration` in `const durationInput = document.querySelector('duration');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a typo it's `this.startButton.addEventListener('click',this.start)` the L goes in uppercase.

Comment: THANK YOU how did I not notice that